# Does there exist a more modern alternative to Latex?

Tags: editors

Sometimes writing in Latex is quite cumbersome. Always something does not work, and some quirky workarounds do have to be applied. Does there nowadays exist a mature more modern alternative, maybe Python-style like?

Edit: The alternative should be free, powerful at setting math equations, and offer everything that Latex does, but not divided into different packages that potentially do not work well together. It is painful in Latex that evertime you need some specific package for something, that should work out of the box. Also, not every package is of high qualitiy.

Comment: That question is far too broad to be answered here. define "alternative"  You could use SILE or Word for example, but not if you are writing for a Journal that accepts LaTeX. (SILE is Lua rather than python but  you may like it:-)

Comment: You've got MSWord... Jokes aside, you should be more specific: should it be free? should it implement a decent line-breaking algorithm? should it be capable of typing math?

Comment: The first two problems go away with practice. The third is only an issue if you want to program your own packages and/or document classes.

Comment: or try context.

Comment: Have you ever looked at ConTeXt?

Comment: I think the most useful alternatives right now are [RMarkdown](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/) or [Jupyter Book](https://jupyterbook.org/). Both can produce relatively high quality pdf files from markdown, can do math, citations, graphics, etc, and include macro capabilities via r/python. They lack the detailed typography and layout options of latex, but are much simpler in terms of syntax and build process.

Comment: It's [Typst](https://github.com/typst/typst)